# How to add contents of a file to listview C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, listview, windows-forms-designer

The file name is contacts.txt.
Its contents are:

```
line 1: Adam
line 2: adam@gmail.com
line 3: Kris
line 4: kris@gmail.com
```

I have a listview named `listview1`. It has 2 columns, `ColumnHeader1` & `ColumnHeader2`

I want to add the name in the file to `ColumnHeader1` and email to `ColumnHeader2`, i.e, like:

```
Adam    adam@gmail.com
Kris    kris@gmail.com
```

How do I do that?

Also, I want this to happen automatically every time the form is loaded.

Thank You in advance.

Tried this.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Contacts.txt"))
{
    while (sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(sr.ReadLine());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        continue;
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: Answer Please.
how can i make the listview loaded with items on form is loaded

Comment: i just had to use ! in while loop
everything else works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `continue` word out. It shouldn't be necessary.

Try something like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Contacts.txt"))
{
  while (-1 < sr.Peek())
  {
    try
    {
      string name = sr.ReadLine();
      string email = sr.ReadLine(); 
      var lvi = new ListViewItem(name);
      lvi.SubItems.Add(email);
      listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    } catch (Exception) { }
  }
  sr.Close();
}
```

That `try/catch` is there just in case there are not an even number of entries in your file.

Comment: i just had to use ! in while loop.
but still how can i make the listview loaded with items automaticlly on form loaded

Comment: Double Click your form from the designer view. That will create the `Form_Load` event and code it to your form (if it does not already exist). Then, just place the code above inside that routine.

Comment: what a dumbass am i.
forgot the basic thing.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Don't worry. You are not alone. I do dumbass stuff all the time.

Comment: ive a contextmenustrip ive added options like
add remove update.
how to disable some of them

Comment: Name the ContextMenuStrip items something meaningful, like `cmsAdd` and `cmsUpdate`, then either disable them, like `cmsAdd.Enabled = false;` or hide them using `cmsUpdate.Visible = false;`